# JAVA - USACO Can't Solve - Record Keeping

Tags: java, algorithm

Here's the problem.

http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=358

I can't find an efficient way of solving the problem. I thought of alphabetically organizing each group of cows, which would make them easier to compare. After that, I could simply find the mode. However, the algorithmic problem I'm having is that the number of groups of cows that are presented to me are different in every input. I was planning to set each group of cows to a single String, but that would obviously not work because the number of groups can vary. Any idea on a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction. Still you can go a step further - after sorting each group alphabetically, sort all the groups in lexicographical order. Let's take the example:

```
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
FRAN BESSIE INGRID
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
MATILDA INGRID FRAN
ELSIE BESSIE MATILDA
```

After the first step you've already suggested these will become:

```
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
BESSIE FRAN INGRID
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
FRAN INGRID MATILDA
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
```

And then sort the whole groups:

```
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
BESSIE ELSIE MATILDA
BESSIE FRAN INGRID
FRAN INGRID MATILDA
```

The second step can be done by considering the whole string used to represent the group. After this sorting, the problem can be finished up with one linear pass(I am leaving this to you to figure).

The approach I suggest will work because the input is relatively small and thus the solution will not be too slow. For bigger constraints you should do the second step(after sorting the names in each group) using hashing. You can apply this approach to your problem too, but it is a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm a little confused about what you mean by "considering the whole string used to represent the group." Do you mean that I would store every single group of cows into one String?

Comment: This one way you can implement the sorting but you don't *have* to use it. I am not sure if in Java you can sort an array of arrays out of the box but essentially that is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to this problem, I hope it helps, this is the best solution I coud think in the contest and it pass all the testcases.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class records {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("records.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("records.out"));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for(int i = 1; i<=n ;i++){
            String str = bf.readLine();
            char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(chars);
            String sorted = new String(chars);

            if(map.containsKey(sorted)){
                int count = map.get(sorted);
                map.put(sorted, count + 1);
            }else{
                map.put(sorted, 1);
            }
        }

        /*for (String name : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + map.get(name));
        }*/

        List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(c);
        pw.println(c.get(c.size() -1));
        pw.close();
    }
}
```